# Node js Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 52.**.**.***:1122

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, networking, server

Node js application in local it works fine. When tried running in server it shows error.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-*-*-*:~/sample_nodejs$ node main.js
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 52.*.*.*:1122
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
at doListen (net.js:1517:7)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

And here is my port running status. Used command **netstat -tulpn**

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      
-
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      
-
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           
-
udp        0      0 172.*.*.*:68          0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Tried changing iptables

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

still it shows the error. Is this server fault or i need ask permission from server side?

here is my sample code i tried using public ip address:

```
   var express = require('express');

  var app = express();

 const http = require('http');

  const hostname = '52.*.*.*';

  const port = 1122;

  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello, World!\n');
  });

  server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
   });
```

Comment: this url helped me to find answer https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-2-5fbdea95f8a1

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to listen on the external IP address on an EC2 instance - it isn't available.  Instead, listen on the "any" interface (sometimes shown as `0.0.0.0`).  According to the docs I can find this is done with [server.listen](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback) without specifying a host parameter:

> If `host` is omitted, the server will accept connections on the
>   [unspecified IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Unspecified_address) (`::`) when IPv6 is available, or the
>   [unspecified IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) (`0.0.0.0`) otherwise.
>
> In most operating systems, listening to the [unspecified IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Unspecified_address)
>   (`::`) may cause the `net.Server` to also listen on the [unspecified IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) (`0.0.0.0`).

The port you listen on will be accessible from the outside world though you will have to expose it with a security group.

**EDIT**

You'll need to change your code to be:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

const http = require('http');

const port = 1122;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello, World!\n');
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering . hey i'm new to this. cna you check my sample code which i have tried so far. how to check this in browser?

Answer (score 1):

As stundbar said, when you make a server, you mustn't set the public IP but 0.0.0.0 or localhost. 
Don't set 127.0.0.1 because you won't be able to access it outside the server's machine.

Comment: thanks for answering . hey i'm new to this. cna you check my sample code which i have tried so far. how to check this in browser?

Comment: Sure. Do you have discord to speak about this?

Comment: Okay, send me a mail at darkscientist@hynity.com

Comment: hey i have installed discord

Comment: Okay, add me in friend : DarkScientist_#9449