# Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available **.***.***.**:3004

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, debian, apache2, google-compute-engine

I have installed **node.js** on a google cloud server. But I'm getting an error while running the command **sudo node test.js**. The web root is /var/www/*******/ and the virtual host file is /etc/apache2/*****.conf

I'm trying to access it through the port 3004. I have enabled it in the firewall as well.

**Virtual host configuration**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domainname.com
        ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/******/"

        <Directory "/var/www/******/">
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:3004>
        ServerName domainname.com
        ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/******/"

        <Directory "/var/www/******/">
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</Virtualhost>
```

===============================================================

**Error**:

```
Server running at http://domainname.com:3004/
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available **.***.***.**:3004
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1239:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1304:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1443:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:63:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1283:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Vishnu.

Comment: possbile duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955562/node-js-error-listen-eaddrnotavail-52-1122

Comment: Can you share how did you set the firewall rules?